# OSX webcam program that takes screenshots when it detects movement

Tags: macos, display, webcam, motion-detection

I'm looking for a webcam program for OSX that will detect when the computer is idle for more than a certain amount of time (say, 5 minutes), then turn on the webcam and take an image every time it detects movement. Does anyone know of a program that fits the bill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [EvoCam](http://www.evological.com/evocam.html).  Or [Iris](http://www.mildmanneredindustries.com/iris/).
EvoCam is a little more fully-featured.

I'm not aware of any freeware solutions, without writing your own.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at both and decided to go with Iris.

Comment: Iris appears no longer available